# Access user email address in Meteor JS app

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I am building an app using Meteor and need to access the stored email address of a logged-in user.

I am currently using:

```
var userObj = Meteor.user();
console.log(userObj);
```

to access the user. However, I am only able to access the id. The email address is stored in a nested object that looks like this:

```
[Object {address="address@gmail.com", verified=false}]
```

I have tried various ways to traverse the JSON object but can't figure out how to access the value I need.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Meteor.user().emails[0].address` works for me.

Here's what the doc says:

> By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile. See
>   [Meteor.users](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) for more on the fields used in user documents.

Example user document:

```
{
  _id: "bbca5d6a-2156-41c4-89da-0329e8c99a4f",  // Meteor.userId()
  username: "cool_kid_13", // unique name
  emails: [
    // each email address can only belong to one user.
    { address: "cool@example.com", verified: true },
    { address: "another@different.com", verified: false }
  ],
  createdAt: 1349761684042,
  profile: {
    // The profile is writable by the user by default.
    name: "Joe Schmoe"
  },
  services: {
    facebook: {
      id: "709050", // facebook id
      accessToken: "AAACCgdX7G2...AbV9AZDZD"
    },
    resume: {
      loginTokens: [
        { token: "97e8c205-c7e4-47c9-9bea-8e2ccc0694cd",
          when: 1349761684048 }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify how you are authenticating users. For example, if you were using Google authentication only, the email address would be found only in

```
Meteor.user().services.google.email
```

So, it depends.

Comment: If his console has the object he posted in the OP, then he's using accounts-passwords or something similar, he just hasn't figured out how to access the properties correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Meteor.user().emails[0].address

Regards,