# Get emails address of current logged in user

Tags: meteor

I tried this

```
console.log(Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},{fields: {'emails.address': 1}}));
```

in server side but it's displaying

```
I20140315-12:06:08.588(6)? undefined
```

So how do I get current user details like email address ?

Comment: Does this help: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004245/access-user-email-address-in-meteor-js-app)

Comment: TL;DR: `Meteor.user().emails[0].address`

Comment: App is crashing after trying console.log(Meteor.user().emails[0].address) @Cuberto

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use this code? On the server side it's not always obvious what do you mean by current user, and the usage varies depending on where you are.

Comment: I have tried this code in server side . @HubertOG

Comment: Yes, you've written this. But where? In a method? Allow callback? Publish function?

Comment: Is it possible that record does not include an email address?  You can configure the user accounts to just use a user name, which may be how it comes initially IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure your emails are published:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: { emails: 1, profile: 1 } });
});
```

Then you can just do (Server or client)

```
var user = Meteor.user();
var email = user && user.emails && user.emails[0].address

console.log(email);
```

Will return `null` if the user is not logged in/your subscriptions are not yet ready, or the user has no emails set.

If you're using it in a `Meteor.publish` function you will need to use an alternative to `Meteor.user()` and fetch the user data manually.

If you are doing this from within a callback from an npm module you need to wrap your callback in a **[Meteor.bindEnvironment](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-what-is-meteor-bindenvironment)** to ensure that your callback runs in the same fiber. In general you can't use Meteor code in these callbacks without bindEnvironment.

Comment: App is crashing
W20140315-13:03:33.579(6)? (STDERR) /home/prism/.meteor/tools/f3947a4651/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140315-13:03:33.579(6)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);

Comment: Are you doing this in a callback from an npm module? or a setTimeout?

Comment: @prism see my updated answer. Also please mention a bit more code of the context of where you are running it. If it is a callback from an npm module, a publish function, a meteor method or the client side there are different methods required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do 'findOne' rather than 'find'.  Find returns a cursor which must be accessed with fetch(), forEach(), or map().  FindOne returns an object which can be logged.

[Documentation here](http://docs.meteor.com/#findone).

Comment: Tried this before. Returning same result