# How to get logged in user's email address via third party services on the client or server?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

This gives you logged in user's email address via accounts-password.

```
Meteor.user().emails[0].address
```

How can I get email addresses on the client/server when users use third party services to login? E.g. facebook, google.

I want to call the following method from the client

```
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function() {
        var userEmail;
        if(Meteor.user().emails[0].address) {
            return userEmail = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
        } else if (Meteor.user().services.google.email) {
            return userEmail = Meteor.user().services.google.email;
        } else if (Meteor.user().services.facebook.email) {
            return userEmail = Meteor.user().services.facebook.email;
        }
        Email.send({
            to: userEmail,
            from: "example@gmail.com",
            subject: "some subject",
            text: "sometext"
        });
    }
});
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Could you please try: `Meteor.user().services.google.email`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access user email address in Meteor JS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004245/access-user-email-address-in-meteor-js-app)

Comment: No luck, both on the client and server.

Comment: this is basic javascript, if `Meteor.user().emails` doesn't exist, then you'll get an error if you ask for `Meteor.user().emails[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this but it works this way

```
Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function() {
        this.unblock();
        var currentUser = Meteor.user();
        if (currentUser && currentUser.emails && currentUser.emails[0] 
            && currentUser.emails[0].address) {
            var userEmail = currentUser.emails[0].address;
            Email.send({
                to: userEmail,
                from: "something@gmail.com",
                subject: "something",
                text: "something"
            });
        } else if (currentUser && currentUser.services && currentUser.services.google 
            && currentUser.services.google.email) {
            var userEmail = currentUser.services.google.email;
            Email.send({
                to: userEmail,
                from: "something@gmail.com",
                subject: "something",
                text: "something"
            });
        } else if (currentUser && currentUser.services && currentUser.services.facebook 
            && currentUser.services.facebook.email) {
            var userEmail = currentUser.services.facebook.email;
            Email.send({
                to: userEmail,
                from: "something@gmail.com",
                subject: "something",
                text: "something"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I think it just assumes that it can send an email to empty string/null/undefined. I tried to throw Meteor.Error on `if(!userEmail)` no luck. If someone can make this code neater I'd appreciate it.

Comment: glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.call('sendEmail', function(error) {
  if (error) {
    if (error.error === 'user-not-found') {
      console.log('Error: User not found');
    } else if (error.error === 'email-not-found') {
      console.log('Error: User email not found');
    } else {
      console.log('Error sending email:', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent successfully');
  }
});
```

It will work like a charm in your case